# Parsing a string to date format in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a string like this 
String s= '19910127'
I want to parse this and convert in into 01/27/1991 date format.
How can this be achieved in Javascript?

Comment: Yes, what did you try yourself, and date formatting is a b*tch in JS.

Comment: Have you at least researched this already? What have you tried?

Comment: is that in the format YYYY-MM-DD?

Comment: @Anthony, yes, logic dictates there is no other format possible.

Comment: @Mouser whoops didn't see the `01/27/1991` in his question xD

Comment: I tried this one  var date =Date.parse('19910127', "yyyy-MM-dd", null);
                console.log(date.getDate()); But this did not work

Comment: @coder7 new Date() provides some funny results ...

Comment: For this purpose, i'd use moment.js

Comment: why write 3 lines of actual JS when you can mindlessly inject thousands of lines someone else wrote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Use substring:*

```js
s="19910127";
var year = s.substring(0, 4);
var month = s.substring(4, 6);
var day = s.substring(6, 8);
document.getElementById("out").innerHTML=month+"/"+day+"/"+year;
```

```html
<span id="out"></span>
```

Comment: aside from this not actually parsing the date, i suppose it can work...

Answer (score 0):

Split the input string and create a new Date object:

```
var input = "19910127";
var y = input.substr(0, 4);
var m = input.substr(4, 2);
var d = input.substr(6, 2);

var output = new Date(y, m, d);
```

Comment: this is nice because it uses locale time

Answer (score 0):

With regex you could:

```js
var str = '19910127'

var df = str.match(/(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})/).slice(1,4).join('-')

var d = new Date(df)

console.log(d)
```

Comment: don't forget to add some timezone info to the replaced string to avoid wrong dates

Answer (score 0):

Simple.

```js
const str = '19912701'

const formatDate = (s) => s.substring(0,4) + '/' + s.substring(4,6) + '/' + s.substring(6,8)

console.log(formatDate(str))
```